# Why raycast doesn't hit any collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to make a roulette racetrack for a mobile game.

[image]

There is 37 box(sprite) in the racetrack,
each square box have a Box Collider 2D and each rounded box have a Polygon Collider 2D.

my code:

```
  void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction*100, Color.yellow, 100f);
            Debug.Log("Touch Something");
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log("Something Hit");
                Debug.Log(hit.collider);
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("collider Hit");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I would like to do something when I hit the collider of a box.
When I test my code, the only debug.log that work is "Debug.Log("Touch Something")".

result for Debug.DrawRay

[image]

We can see that the raycast doesn't hit any collider but I don't know what I should change, please help! ^^

Comment: Can you `debug.drawray(ray)`? Tell us what you see.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using

    Physics2D.Raycast instead of Physics.Raycast?

Comment: @Walter I edit my post and add debug.drawray

Comment: @Hasnain I think that too but all the videos or post I found use Physics.Raycast, even for 2d project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace my 2D colliders by 3D colliders and now everythings is working.